# Haskell IO function for various data types

Tags: haskell, io

I know almost nothing about [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) and I'm reading lots of tutorials and code samples to understand **Haskell**'s IO, but it is still not clear to me.

All examples are like:

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "Hello, what's your name?"  
    name <- getLine  
    putStrLn ("Hey " ++ name ++ ", welcome !")
```

They read a string from IO and there are many other examples that do some customization on input that I don't understand.

My question is simply: How to read `Int`, `Float`, `Double` or `Char` like using `scanf` in **C** with a format string?

And can anyone help me with a clear explanation to IO customization or tricks?

> Hint: if the code comes with a main function that would
>   be great - it would make testing easier.

I have very good coding experience in `C`, `C++`, `Java`, `C#`, `Matlab` and `PHP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isturdy's answer is valid, but in case you want something a bit simpler, the easiest approach is to do it step-by-step:

```
main = do
    i' <- getLine -- some integral input; it will be received as a String
    d' <- getLine -- some floating input; also will be received as a String
    let i = read i' :: Int -- i is an Int now
        d = read d' :: Double -- d is a Double now
    putStr "" -- so that GHC doesn't complain
```

The type of `getLine` is `IO String` - it reads input as a `String`. You can then change the type of this string with `read` (and indicating what type you want). As for a `scanf`-like experience, you can try something like this:

```
main = do
    inp <- getLine -- the input is an Int, a String and a Double, like: 4 derp 2.7
    let list = words inp -- divide the input String into a list of Strings
        val = read (list !! 0) :: Int -- val equals 4, its type is Int
        str = list !! 1 -- str is a String ("derp"), no additional action required
        dbl = read (list !! 2) :: Double -- dbl equals 2.7 and is a Double
    putStr ""
```

Comment: That's so simple, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `readMaybe`! `read` is not total, it will crash your program when the input is not the type it should be.

Answer (score 4):

The most direct way is to use `read` (you will often have to provide an explicit type), as in

```
main = do  
    putStrLn "Hello, what's your age?"  
    age <- liftM read getLine :: IO Int
    putStrLn ("Hey " ++ (show age)  ++ ", welcome !")
```

This works well if you know that the string contains just the single value (it throws an exception if it cannot parse the string as the desired datatype). For more complex parsing, I usually jump straight to the [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec.html) parser combinator library (which is probably all the parser you will ever need in Haskell, but also handles simple jobs with minimal overhead). If that does not suit you a quick search of Hackage reveals some candidate libraries offering a simpler scanf-like function: see, among others, [Text.XFormat.Read](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xformat/0.1/doc/html/Text-XFormat-Read.html) and [Text.PrintScan](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/liboleg/2010.1.2/doc/html/Text-PrintScan.html), although I cannot personally vouch for either.

Comment: You code it good but is there any `Try.. Catch` mechanism to handle such exception in haskell?

And I wonder if you can explain what is `LiftM` ? is it a keyword or just a variable name ? also for `read` .

I understand that `getLine` is a function, what is `::` and `IO Int` is for ?

And I think that `Show` is also a function, Am I right ?

I'm sorry for these noob questions, but you'd give me a great help if you could make you answer very detailed.

Comment: @SamehKamal As of the ``:: IO Int``, `read` is of type `Read a => String -> a` and so if you infer the type of `liftM read getLine` you just get `Read a => IO a`. Since you want to read an `Int`, you have to help the type inferer and specify that `liftM read getLine :: IO Int`, and then `read` will be forced to be of type `String -> Int`.

Comment: @SamehKamal `Show` is a typeclass, whose only function is `show :: Show a => a -> String`.

Comment: @SamehKamal `liftM :: Monad m => (a1 -> r) -> m a1 -> m r`, or in this specific case (where `m ~ IO`) it is `(a -> r) -> IO a -> IO r`.

Comment: @SamehKamal Haskell has some exception control, but if there's a chance that `read` might fail, you might prefer to use `maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`.

Comment: @RamonSnir Your explaination is great but can you explain more about the arrows and colons `::` , `->` , `=>` , I don't get what it's for.

Comment: @SamehKamal `a -> b` means a function which receives an `a` and returns a `b`. `a :: t` means that `a` is of type `t` (uncommon, mostly done for cases where you want to force the type inferer, as was with our `read` function). `Class t => ...` means that `t` in `...`, is any type (a generic parameter), but only of the types which are an instance of the typeclass `Class`. If you don't get `=>`, you should really read about typeclasses, which are a prime feature of Haskell.

Comment: Great ! , Now all what reminds is explanation why `maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a` will avoid exceptions ? by what you said above that `maybeRead :: somthing` means that `maybeRead` is of type of `something` and the exception is omitted in evaluating `something` itself, How do this avoid the exception ?

Comment: @SamehKamal: A value of type `Maybe a` is either `Just a` (that is, single value of type `a`) or `Nothing`. Instead of throwing an exception, `maybeRead` signalizes error by returning `Nothing` (as in: there was nothing I could parse). For example, assuming `maybeRead :: String -> Maybe Int`: `maybeRead "12" == Just 12` and `maybeRead "abc" == Nothing`.

Answer (score 1):

You should dig into Read typeclass. It is a standard typecalss for values that can be read from string and very useful in controlled environment when there is no need for error reporting. If you wish to read your own datatype, you probably have to use `deriving Read` statement.

However, if one want to read arbitrary input, it is standard to use [parsec](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html) library. Parsec is parser combinator library with several predefined basic parsers. An [extra package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-numbers) provides many parsers for numbers. Special hi-speed parser combinator libraries and parser generator also exist.